Is it possible to retain WhatsApp media on PC and not on phone?
First the question - is it somehow possible to install the PC WhatsApp program for Windows and use the PC for complete storage (chat and all media) while maintaining only chat history on my phone? I understand that installing the PC app will transfer all history to my PC but that any changes will be mirrored across devices - although I'm not sure (e.g. could I go into a folder on my phone and manually delete old media and would this be reflected on my PC)?
My motivation:
I've been using WhatsApp for several years now and it's nice to be able to occasionally navigate my history for various reasons. My current decent phone's display broke (but still works with via a mouse) and it isn't a viable repair. I'd like to lighten my footprint on this planet and make do with an old Samsung phone that's been lying around and is adequate in most respects for at least a few more years except it has <2GB free once every bloody pre-installed non-removeable app adds all its bloat. Since WhatsApp doesn't play nice with SD cards and my history is far in excess of free space, I basically can't transfer it to this phone at present. I really don't know if there is a migration path that would retain media on my PC - which I'd prefer anyway - and still allow me to get immediate messages on this phone. Without knowing if this would work, my attempt might look like: transfer everything from my broken phone to the PC, wipe media files from the broken phone, attempt to migrate chat history from the broken phone to the Samsung while retaining media on my PC. But I'd rather not experiment on this and get stuck with a destroyed history.
Thanks for any insights!
